# Rejecting deliver request because of consenter error

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

We have a ongoing project running on Fabric 1.0.1.. We are struck at an issue. Basically the environment we have is 3 orderers/kafkas/zookeerps - 2 on one server and 1 on another for all 3
We had a system upgrade and had to restart all of the dockers.

Now the orderer shows below warnings: 2018-06-19 20:56:23.992 UTC [orderer/common/deliver] Handle -> WARN 407 [channel: channel] Rejecting deliver request because of consenter error
whenever we post a transaction we get the error below
2018-06-19 20:43:15.522 UTC [orderer/kafka] Enqueue -> DEBU 376 [channel: channnel] Enqueueing envelope...
2018-06-19 20:43:15.522 UTC [orderer/kafka] Enqueue -> WARN 377 [channel: channel] Will not enqueue, consenter for this channel hasn't started yet

Answer (score -1):

Please try to clear logs of all peer and kafka also.And restart the network IF you find any clue for happening this then please let us know.

Comment: yes we will loose the data. Can you check your peers. It seems like your peer is not functioning properly

Comment: peers are working fine. Is there no other way to get this working without loosing data ? Its a production environment,.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution not involving the loose of all data?, we're stuck with the same issue. Thanks.